# angular 2+ after apply filter pipe for loop index displays indexes from original list

Tags: angular, angular7

angular7

in template i am printing a value of i which is index of the loop. i notice after it filter the values index of the for loop still shows index value from the original array ? i want to see the index of filtered array instead, any help is appreciated

### template.html

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items | filterItems: filterStr" let-i="index">
<div>{{i}}</div>
<ng-template>
```

### pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterItems'})
export class FilterItemsPipe implements PipeTransform{

 public transform(items: Item[], itemType: string){
  items.filter(condition);
   function condition(item: Item): boolean {
      return itemType == item.itemType;
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, could you create a demo for this?

Comment: .. probably a typo, but missing a return in your pipe :)